# htmlentities - How do I keep my form safe in PHP?

Tags: php, html-encode, html-escape-characters

I have a small contact form that requires a subject, a name, an email, and a message. All these fields are sanitized with:

```
function sanitize($string){
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

I send the email using the `mail()` function from PHP, and I use the `subject` field as the email title/subject. The problem is that in subject I have a single quote:

```
I'd like to explore
```

But after I sanitize it I get the email in the inbox, but that single quote is sanitized and appears like this:

```
I&#039;d like to explore
```

How do I keep my form safe, but at the same time how do I get my subject of the email to be with the single quote not with that `&#039;d`-thing?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Safety comes from how you handle user generated input. Htmlentities is useful when you want to print user generated content as html.yet if you treat is a plain text, you can store it as such. You don't need to jump through the conversion process.

Comment: @k0pernikus you should put that all in an answer

Comment: Encoding is not the same thing as sanitization. Encoding as HTML doesn't help in email, database, JavaScript, URLs etc. Don't blindly encode everything as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You store data using your `sanitize` function and if you want to display the data, you need to "desanitize" to the original format.

```
$str = 'I&#039;d like to explore';

echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

To be strict, storing any data is not a security risk. However the process how the data is stored can cause security issues. Using HTML entities is usually done for storing data in databases and use it later on. But a better way to store that data is by using prepared statements which makes this completely unnecessary.

The question really is, for what storage you are *sanitizing*.

Comment: I just want to send an email to my roundcube email address so basicly you're saing i don't need to sanitize that form for just sending the email ? :-?

Comment: You do need to sanitize for malformed input, perhaps a (re)captcha to avoid bots from sending mails. Also it *heavily depends on what you're sending in the form*, files perhaps? If so filter on specific file types. But the short answer would be no.

Comment: I'm sending only text: 3 radio buttons - to choose a subject, a name, an email and a message - there is no file - and i also insert their email in a database if a checkbox is checked - so i guess i should sanitize only that email but i actually already prepare(PDO prepare function) that before exectuing the query. But i'm concerd with roundcube, if i don't sanitize those fields is there anything that can go wrong for roundcube? :-s

Comment: Sanitize is the name `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` , check if the email is correct with filter_var and verify the check boxes are just booleans. That's about it.

Comment: @emma I disagree with the `filter_var` for the email check, as it only works on latin chars (no UTF8) and it rejects valid email address that RFC5321 allows. I rather treat email addresses as plain text as well. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#112492

Comment: @k0pernikus You will find that PHP has undergone some changes in [4 years](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/8f4050709c833b9d42cd65349b7747f8e61d171f#diff-a61ab806f8c2193851acdd3eb5f37232) time adding RFC 6531 (Internationalized email addresses). Even so, those unique email addresses are very unlikely to appear.

Comment: @Xorifelse Independent of of the language, I treat email addresses as raw text. Any validation script in my experience will most likely reject that one edge case that should have been valid to begin with. IMO validation of email address is rarely worth it. (At most I check for the existence of an `@` on the frontend. I'll trust that the user knows their email address. I cannot prevent their errors and those cases have a way of solving themselves out.)

Answer (score 0):

`htmlentities` is used when you want to print user-generated content as HTML on your own site. User-generated content could contain HTML-breaking symbols, so it replaces characters with HTML entities. (A wrong `'` could terminate a string or if a troll inserts `</div>`, you entire layout of your website would break.)

That `&#039;`-thing is a `'` and *is*, from the perspective of any html-rendering-engine, an apostrophe and will be displayed as such. You can find [a list of these entities online](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

The reverse of that process is `html_entity_decode`, in order to get plain text out of it again.

In regards to your use case of keeping your form safe: `htmlentities` is the not the right tool for this.

If you want to send that email with plain text, keep it as plain text. It's true that you should not trust user-generated content and behavior, yet you then should safeguard against database insertion issues (prepared statements) and preventing POST-repetition on the form itself in order to not spam people.

Yet there is no inherent harm in treating user input as raw text and sending that content as raw text. (If you want to to send an HTML email with user-generated content, then `htmlentities` will come in handy for that as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Sanitization is done within a context. In other words you should know what you are "sanitizing" against: SQL injection, html script attacks or what not. With this in mind, the correct approach is to deal with each problem separately: sanitize for the SQL injection when storing in the db, but store the data as close to the "original" as you can. This means the data in the db will be "desanitized". Then, depending on what you intend to do with the data, you process it accordingly: sending in an email? Just dump the content. Showing on the web page? `html_entities` it.

Note that the question of "optimization" in the sense of not having to process with a sanitizer every time you output content is different. It has to be dealt with separately, if at all needed.

This has proven itself a sound approach for me over years.